# Too many positional arguments: 2 expected, but 3 found.Try removing the extra arguments Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, arguments

I don't understand the issue here. Checked similar posts here and they do not help.

[image: code creating issues]

Attached the part of the code which my IDE points me to

Comment: Just close the `Navigator.push()` with another closing bracket. Like so: `BatteryGraph()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Line 44 you need one more at the end `)` and `;`

in Line 46 you have to delete `)`

It should be like:

```
onTap:(){
    Navigator.push(
       context, MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) =>BatteryGraph()));

    debugPrint('Landscape tapped');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 44 should end with a ';' not a ',' and your debug print has an extra ')'.